# Reversing a String in C using loops

Tags: c

This code is for converting a decimal number in its equivalent in any base numeric system.

The reversed result is stored in temp.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    long decimal;
    int b = 0,i = 0,n,j = 0;
    printf("Enter Decimal Number :");
    scanf("%ld",&decimal);
    char temp[decimal],base[decimal];
    printf("Enter Base :");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    for(;decimal != 0;decimal /= b){    
      n = decimal % b;
      if(n >= 0 && n <= 9)
      temp[i++] = n + 48;
      else if(n >= 10)
      temp[i++] = n + 55;
    }
    for(j = 0;i >= 0;) //Reversing temp and storing it in base
       base[j++] = temp[i--];
       printf("Base Equivalent : %s",temp);
       printf("Base Equivalent : %s",base);
    return 0;
}
```

The temp part need to be reversed to get the correct result, yet, temp does not get reversed and stored in base. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You need a NULL terminator: `base[j]=0`

Answer (score 1):

```
char temp[decimal],base[decimal];
```

wow. What if decimal is negative? Do you really need to allocate 4GB memory to convert `2147483647`? Thank god you do not read `long long int` Then it would require `2*9 223372036854775807` bytes (many hundreds of petabytes) of memory

Use functions for similar tasks:

```
char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char *wrk = str, *end = str;

    if(str && *str)
    {
        while(*(end + 1)) end++;
        while(end > wrk)
        {
            char temp = *end;
            *end-- = *wrk;
            *wrk++ = temp;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is in the line `base[j++] = temp[i--];`. Note that the `i--` expression returns the value of `i` *before* the decrement (and then decrements `i`). You need the *predecrement* operation, instead:

```c
for (j = 0; i > 0;) // Note the change to i > 0
    base[j++] = temp[--i];
```

There is also a potential issue with the lengths of your character arrays. Why do you assume the value of the input number (`decimal`) will be appropriate for the length of those string?<sup>1</sup> Give them fixed lengths, instead – one that will be large enough to handle all cases. You also don't add the required `nul` terminators to your strings; this can be achieved by initialising them with 'empty' strings (will which set all elements to zero):

```c
char temp[64] = "", base[64] = "";
```

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, for an input of `2` and a base of `2`, the string required for the binary representation (`10`) will need to be **3** characters long (one for the terminator).

Answer (score 0):

strings in c must be null-terminated.
You just need to add `'\0'` to the end of both of your array to make it work.

e.g.:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    long decimal;
    int b = 0,i = 0,n,j = 0;
    printf("Enter Decimal Number :");
    scanf("%ld",&decimal);
    char temp[64],base[64];
    printf("Enter Base :");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("MM: %ld, %d", decimal, b);
    for(;decimal != 0;decimal /= b){    
      n = decimal % b;
      if(n >= 0 && n <= 9)
      temp[i++] = n + 48;
      else if(n >= 10)
      temp[i++] = n + 55;
    }

    // add null terminators
    temp[i] = '\0';
    base[i] = '\0';
    i--;

    for(j = 0;i >= 0;) //Reversing temp and storing it in base
       base[j++] = temp[i--];
       printf("Base Equivalent : %s",temp);
       printf("Base Equivalent : %s",base);
    return 0;
}
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/51bMebd4Y)

Comment: He does still need to terminate `base` with a `\0`.

Comment: they should both be properly terminated, at least asan wasn't screaming about it :D

Comment: I've added the termination part and the code works. Thanks!